# SQL Query excluding some values based on filters

Tags: sql

Newbie here. Trying to see if there's a way to run a single query that total the values of the fields but excludes certain ones.
Currently, when I run the following:
Select col1,col2,col3 from table where CID in (11111,22222,33333,44444,55555)

I get:

| CID | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 10 | 20 | 40 |
| 22222 | 10 | 20 | 40 |
| 33333 | 10 | 20 | 40 |
| 44444 | 10 | 20 | 40 |
| 55555 | 10 | 20 | 40 |

Now I need to add a total but need to exclude col3 if the CID is 44444 or 55555. Something like this below:

| CID | col1 | col2 | col3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 10 | 20 | 40 | 70 |
| 22222 | 10 | 20 | 40 | 70 |
| 33333 | 10 | 20 | 40 | 70 |
| 44444 | 10 | 20 | 40 | 30 |
| 55555 | 10 | 20 | 40 | 30 |

Notice the total value for the last 2 only adds the value from col1 and col2. Is this even possible? The reason is the metrics for certain CID on certain columns shouldn't be counted.
I have something like below but it's excluding everything for those CIDs:
Select col1,col2,col3,(col1+col2+col3 where CID not in (44444,55555)) as total from table where CID in (11111,22222,33333,44444,55555)

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression to conditionally exclude the third column from the total when `CID` be 44444 or 55555.

```sql
SELECT CID, col1, col2, col3,
       col1 + col2 + CASE WHEN CID NOT IN (44444, 55555) THEN col3 ELSE 0 END AS total
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CID;
```